# How to create complex tables in React - React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a `React Table` which will have 13 columns, while for a few columns, we have sub-columns and for a few columns, we have individual columns.

[image: Table]

Suppose in this table columns 1 to 10 are independent. In columns 11 to 13 we have the concept of parent column and sub column.

In the first 10 columns, the columns will have no accessor while columns 6 to 10 will have the accessor of the above column (1 to 5) in one line and their own (6 to 10) accessor in a new line.

How can I realize this functionality?

How to realize these types of columns in React?

Can someone show me a demo of this type of React Table in CodeSandbox?

Comment: Have you attempted to implement this yourself? Once you try to do this yourself after reading the react table guide at https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme, you can return here to ask a more specific question about why something in your code isn't working

Comment: @Richard Stoeffel Yes here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/lyn7r05p9